# how can I see which queries have been sent to the ArangoDB server

Tags: logging, admin, arangodb, aql

I want to quickly gather all queries sent to my ArangoDB server from an application that uses the python-arangodb driver without digging through the source and without resorting to sniffing HTTP traffic to the REST API.

Isn't there some admin/audit log on the ArangoDB web UI which shows me what queries have been sent to the server?

Using 3.2.5 here.

Comment: The web UI only shows slow queries and current queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have all the queries sent to a log file from 3.x and up.

Start with option: `--log.level queries=trace --log.output queries=file:///path/to/queries.log`

From: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/release-notes/version-3.0/whats-new-in-3-0/#logging

The only other way is to implement the logging at the driver level, as far as I know.

Comment: thanks I didn't find this in the docs, so it was hidden in the release notes,-) will try this out...